# Can't add new user to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Trying to add a new SQL Server Authentication user to an Azure SQL Database instance. The script below is being used. I am logged in as the server admin.

But the script fails at the member role assignment. The login and user are created but I cannot login to the database server.

Script:

```
use [master]

CREATE LOGIN test WITH password='somethingsecure';
GO

CREATE USER test FROM LOGIN test;
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'test';

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'test';
```

However the above script fails with the following error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Cannot alter the role 'db_datareader', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Cannot alter the role 'db_datawriter', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: What edition is this? `use` is not supported in Azure SQL. Is this managed instance?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - It is not supported via SSMS, for that you will have to manually switch between the databases, when I run this via my DBUP scripts it works fine.

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments says _In Azure SQL Database, the database parameter can only refer to the current database. If a database other than the current database is provided, the USE statement does not switch between databases, and error code 40508 is returned_ Maybe you're in master or maybe this isn't Azure SQL. I only mention it because database contained users are preferred in Azure SQL over server level users, so you shouldn't be using `CREATE LOGIN` at all.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you are probably right here, I think this worked for me across two runs where the current database changed, testing it again it wasn't allowed. Would you like to add an answer that would work to `CREATE USER` with password rather than using a login? I'd be happy to mark that as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is trying to add the `User` and `Role`s to the `master` database.

All that is needed is to create the `Login` against `master` and then create the `User` and assign `Role`s against the actual database in the Azure SQL Database server.

See modified script:

```
use [master]

CREATE LOGIN test WITH password='somethingsecure';
GO

use [your-database]

CREATE USER test FROM LOGIN test;
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'test';

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'test';
```

Note: If you want to create a User with access to the `master` database, this answer will not help.